# no funciona con contraseña pero sin ella si

Tags: php

Descargué el siguiente código desde esta
[página](http://www.heroesdelaweb.com/threads/sistema-de-registro-y-login-php-mysqli.5980//)
me registro en *local* con *phpmyadmin*, pongo el usuario, me deja entrar, pero si pongo el usuario y  la contraseña me da el `else`, he investigado que tengo que poner `password_verify` pero en el `if` no se dónde colocarlo.

**¿Es en el segundo o en el primer `if`?**

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'php/conexion.php';
?>
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['registrar']) && isset($_REQUEST['reg_agree'])) {
    if ($_REQUEST['contrasena'] === $_REQUEST['contrasenaConfirmar']) {
    $usuario = $_REQUEST['usuario'];
    $password = $_REQUEST['contrasena'];
    $encriptar = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ["cost" => '11']);
    $conexion->query("INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, contrasena) VALUES ('$usuario', '$encriptar')");
    $_SESSION['logged'] = "Logged";
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    $_SESSION['contrasena'] = $encriptar;
    header("Location: index.php");
    } else {
        echo "<div class='error'><span>Las Contraseñas no son iguales</span></div>";
    }
} elseif (isset($_REQUEST['registrar']) && isset($_REQUEST['reg_agree']) === FALSE) {
    echo "<div class='error'><span>Necesitas Estar de Acuerdo con los Términos y Condiciones</span></div>";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<link rel="StyleSheet" href="registro.css" media="all" type="text/css"></link>
<title>Registro</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="login">
        <form id="register-form" class="text-left" method="post">
        <h3>Registro</h3>
            <div class="main-login-form">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="reg_username" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="reg_password" name="Contrasena" placeholder="Contraseña">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="reg_password_confirm" name="ConfirmarContraseña" placeholder="Confirmé contraseña">
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="" id="reg_agree" name="reg_agree">
                        <label for="reg_agree">de acuerdo con los términos y condiciones</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button id="boton" type="submit" class="login-button" name="registrar"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right">Registrarme</i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="etc-login-form">
                <p>Ya tiene una cuenta? <a  style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none;"href="index.php">Login Aquí</a></p>
            </div>
        </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

LOGIN

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'php/conexion.php';
?>
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['iniciar'])) {
    $usuario = $_REQUEST['usuario'];
    $password = $_REQUEST['contrasena'];

    $sql = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario'");
    while ($login = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
        $usuarioDB = $login['usuario'];
        $passwordDB = $login['contrasena'];
    }
    if ($usuario == isset($usuarioDB) && password_verify($password, $passwordDB)) {
        $_SESSION['logged'] = "Logged";
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuarioDB;
        $_SESSION['contrasena'] = $passwordDB;
        header("Location: login.php");
    } elseif ($usuario !== isset($usuarioDB)) {
        echo "<div class='error'><span>El Nombre de Usuario que has Introducido es Incorrecto</span></div>";
    } elseif (password_verify($password, $passwordDB) === FALSE) {
        echo "<div class='hola'><span>La Contraseña que has Introducido es Incorrecta</span></div>";
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">


<head>
<link rel="StyleSheet" href="stilos.css" media="all" type="text/css"></link>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>Hosting</title> 


</head>




<body>
<h1 id="nombre">HostingMinecraft</h1>
<ul id="button">
<li><a style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none;" href="../index.php">Planes</a></li>
<li><a style="color: #fff;text-decoration: none;"href="../servicios/servicios.php">Otros servicios</a></li>
<li><a style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none;"href="../contacto/contacto.php">Soporte</a></li>

</ul>



<div id="loginForm" class="fromlogin">
    <form id="form1">
        <input type="text" size="6" placeholder="Usuario" name="usuario" class="form-control" id="lg_username" ></input>
        <input type="password" size="6" maxlength="10" id="lg_password" name="contrasena" placeholder="Contraseña"/>
        <input type="submit" class="login-button" name="iniciar" value="Iniciar Sesión"></input>
    </form>
</div>
<a href="../recuperaciondecontraseña/contraseña.php" id="olvidarcontraseña">Olvdaste tu contraseña?</a>
<a href="registro.php" id="registro">Registro</a>
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: Quiza tu problema está dentro de el archivo requerido conexion.php el cual quiza debas revisar ¿esto resuelve tu duda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te aconsejo usar sentencias [`preparadas`](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) o [`PDO`](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php), para obtener mayor seguridad, y desde mi punto de vista quizás podrías mejorar un poco la estructura de tu código `PHP`, por ejemplo, podrías usar la función `num_rows` para saber si existe el registro del usuario en tu sentencia y en caso contrario lanza tu error.

> **Nota:** para que funcione mis ejemplos debes añadir el `method="POST"` en tu *formulario login*, ya que por defecto usa el método `GET`.

*Ejemplo actualizado:*

```
<div id="loginForm" class="fromlogin">
    <form id="form1" method="POST">
```

*Ejemplo completo `mysqli::query()`:*

```
if (isset($_POST['iniciar'])) {

    //Datos formulario.
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $password = $_POST['contrasena'];
    //Sentencia
    $sql = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario' LIMIT 1");
    //Comprobamos si existe registro.
    if ($sql->num_rows===1) {
        //Asociamos datos.
        while ($login = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
            //Obtenemos datos desde la Base de datos.
            $usuarioDB = $login['usuario'];
            $passwordDB = $login['contrasena'];
            //Comprobamos contraseña.
            if (password_verify($password, $passwordDB)) {
                $_SESSION['logged'] = "Logged";
                $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuarioDB;
                $_SESSION['contrasena'] = $passwordDB;
                header("Location: login.php");
            } else {
                echo "<div class='hola'><span>La Contraseña que has Introducido es Incorrecta</span></div>";
            }
        } $sql->close();//Cerramos sentencia.
    } else {
        $sql->close();//Cerramos sentencia.
        echo "<div class='error'><span>El Nombre de Usuario que has Introducido es Incorrecto</span></div>";
    }
}
```

*Ejemplo completo `mysqli::prepare`:*

```
if (isset($_POST['iniciar'])) {

    //Datos
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $password = $_POST['contrasena'];

    $sql = $conexion->prepare("SELECT usuario,contrasena FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=? LIMIT 1");
    //Pasamos el parametro por separado ?, la es 's', es decir, es de tipo string (cadena).
    $sql->bind_param("s",$usuario);
    //Ejecutar sentencia.
    $sql->execute();
    //Alamacenamiento base datos.
    $sql->store_result();
    //Comprobamos si existe registro.
    if ($sql->num_rows===1) {
        //Obtenemos datos BD.
        $sql->bind_result($usuarioDB,$passwordDB);      
        while ($sql->fetch()) {         
            //Comprobamos contraseña.
            if (password_verify($password, $passwordDB)) {
                $_SESSION['logged'] = "Logged";
                $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuarioDB;
                $_SESSION['contrasena'] = $passwordDB;
                header("Location: login.php");
            } else {
                echo "<div class='hola'><span>La Contraseña que has Introducido es Incorrecta</span></div>";
            }
        } $sql->close();
    } else {
        $sql->close();
        echo "<div class='error'><span>El Nombre de Usuario que has Introducido es Incorrecto</span></div>";
    }
}
```

> **Nota:** `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` - Usar el algoritmo `CRYPT_BLOWFISH` para crear el hash. Producirá un hash estándar compatible con `crypt()` utilizando el identificador "$2y$". El resultado siempre será un `string` de `60` caracteres, o `FALSE` en caso de error. ***¡Importante que en tu tabla 'usuario' la columna 'contrasena' permita hasta 60 caracteres!***

Si quieres puedes leer este interesante artículo de SOes:
[¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)